# Width of div is not applied by media query

Tags: html, css, css-float, width

I'm trying to make full width horizontal menus using the methods `display:inline-block` as well as `float:left`. It all works, except that the media query is not applying the `width:100%` declaration. The test color is applied though which indicates that the media query is working.

Relevant section from HTML document

```
<nav class="display">
  <!-- Weird comments to prevent space between elements -->
  <div class="navitem">Section 1</div><!--
  --><div class="navitem">Section 2</div><!--
  --><div class="navitem">Section 3</div><!--
  --><div class="navitem">Section 4</div>
</nav>

<nav class="float">
  <div class="navitem">Section 1</div>
  <div class="navitem">Section 2</div>
  <div class="navitem">Section 3</div>
  <div class="navitem">Section 4</div>
</nav>
```

Relevant section from stylesheet

```
.display .navitem {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.float .navitem {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.float::after {
  clear: left;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .navitem {
    width: 100%;
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

I've been trying around for an hour and just can't figure out why the width won't change. What am I missing?

Full code: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/zuba0fge/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use display:flex

html

```
  <nav>
    <div>Section 1</div>
    <div>Section 2</div>
    <div>Section 3</div>
    <div>Section 4</div>
  </nav>
```

css

```
nav > div {
  flex: none;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (min-width:800px) {

  nav {
    display: flex;
  }

  nav > div {
    flex: 1;
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z7w2ms34/

Comment: Thanks, but I want to understand why my code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Because you are applying a style to .float .navitem in one instance, then just .navitem in the second instance. If you apply your 100% width in the media query to .float .navitem it works.

Is there a reason you are styling it this way? It seems overly complicated and not how you'd want to put anything into production. 

https://jsfiddle.net/7jqemaLk/

Comment: That solved it! I never thought .navitem wouldn't be enough because I assumed it works like with normal selectors. The code is just for learning purposes on how to create menus using different methods. Thanks for finding the solution!

Comment: I have found that you need to take care when specifying nested selectors or you end up missing them. The person below made a good point for you while you are learning - to do mobile first and use the media queries to style the larger viewports.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a mobile-first approach to setting your media queries. Also, make sure `.navitem`'s `display` property is not set to be `inline` or you won't be able to apply a width to it.

```
.display .navitem {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.float .navitem {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .display .navitem,
  .float .navitem {
    color: black;
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it doesn't work. Regarding being able to apply a width, yes both divs can take it because they are inline-block and block (default) respectively. Also my media query works fine as indicated by the changing color, the only question is why the width:100% is not applied.